# Is this the most efficient way to sum multiple fields in DataTable using LINQ?

Tags: linq, datatable

I have a datatable with multiple columns. I am interested in getting the summation of three columns of all the records in the table (without grouping). I am using the following code to do that. But I am not sure if the query loops through the datatable three times or only once when the query is executed. Is it the efficient way to do the job with my LINQ expression? Just curious. Thank you.

```
private void getSum()
{
        var s1 = new
        {
            Rowkey = "All",
            STotal = cleanData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Solicit")),
            PTotal = cleanData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Participation")),
            CTotal = cleanData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<double>("TotalCost"))
        };



}
```

Comment: What's the relationship of last statement with your question? If no relationship, can you just remove it?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, just a statement to execute the LINQ query. I removed it per your suggestion.